# Create array from attributes; add them to the page

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I've got a problem that's been racking my brain since I'm rather inexperienced with programming. I'm a member of a website that hosts image galleries. When you view a page with a list of galleries, every gallery has tags underneath it inside of icons.

```
<div class="id4">
    <a href="..."><img src="..."></a>
    <div class="id44">
        <div class="tft" title="tag1, tag2"></div>
        <div class="tft" title="tag3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags"></div>
</div>
<div class="id4">
    <a href="..."><img src="..."></a>
    <div class="id44">
        <div class="tft" title="tag1"></div>
        <div class="tft" title="tag2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags"></div>
</div>
```

Since hovering over each icon is a big hassle, I wanted to write a custom script that writes the tags inside of the "title" attribute underneath the gallery they belong to. This is as far as I could get:

```
$(".id44").after('<div class="tags"></div>');
$(".id44").each(function() {
    var array = [];
    $(".tft").each(function() {
        var tags = $(this).attr("title");
        array.push(tags);
    });
    console.log(array);
});
```

All it does is print a gigantic list of every single tag on the page to the console as many times as there are galleries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `.tft` elements that are descendants of the current element:

```
$(this).find(".tft").each(function() {
    array.push(this.title);
});
```

`$(".tft")` alone matches *all* elements with a class of `tft`.

I would write the whole thing like this:

```
$('.id44').each(function() {
    var tags = $(this).find('.tft').map(function() {
        return this.title;
    }).get();

    $('<div>', {
        'class': 'tags',
        'text': tags.join(', ')
    }).insertAfter(this);
});
```

`.map(...).get()` is just a shorter way of writing the code that makes an array of all the tags.

Comment: This functions perfectly, thank you. I have one more small question regarding the tags. Some of them have namespaces attached to them (eg: "namespaceX:tag1" "namespaceY:tag2") How can I strip those from the output?

Comment: @user1689634: Just do `this.title.split(':').slice(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.tft` is not limited to the current `.id44` you are looping over. Using `"selector", this` will limit the result to the `this`-container. In addition, I've added how to add the tags in the right `.tag-div`.

```
$(".id44").after('<div class="tags"></div>');
$(".id44").each(function() {
    var array = [];
    $(".tft", this).each(function() {
        var tags = $(this).attr("title");
        array.push(tags);
    });
    $(".tags", this).html(array.join(','));
});
```

Comment: I didn't know `"selector", this` was possible, thank you. That helps a lot.